# authentication for specific express routes in passport javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mern

authentication for specific express routes in passport javascript

`how to authenticate specific routes in passport js`

is there a way by which I can authenticate specific routes in passport js

Please help me out...

Answer (score 0):

Just specify the Passport middleware for that route.

```
app.get('/authenticated', passport.authenticate('strategy'), (req, res) => ...)
```